# Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactional

I'm working on a project using JSpring and JPA/Hibernate. I try to call a native query to update the DB. Here is the error trace:

`Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.ncrm.dao.daoImpl.UpdateExt(daoImpl.java:124)
    at com.ncrm.metier.MetierImpl.UpdateExt(MetierImpl.java:663)
    at com.ncrm.loginBean.authentification(loginBean.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)`

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ncrm.dao" />
    <bean name="daoo" class="com.ncrm.dao.daoImpl"></bean>

    <bean name="metier" class="com.ncrm.metier.MetierImpl">
    <property name="dao" ref="daoo"></property>
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean name="paramEtat" class="com.ncrm.editionEtats.dao.paramEtatsImp"></bean> -->

    <!-- ############################################################################## -->
                        <!-- le gestionnaire de transactions -->
   <!-- ############################################################################## -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jpaTransactionManager" />
    <bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" />
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jpaTransactionManager" />
    <bean id="jpaTransactionManagerBPa" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBeanBpa" />
    </bean>


    <!-- ############################################################################## -->
                         <!-- couche de persistance JPA -->
   <!-- ############################################################################## -->


    <bean id="localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
         <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:config/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ncrm_extraction" />  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="basicDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="showSql" value="false"></property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean id="instrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBeanBpa"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:config/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="BpaProduciton" />  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="basicDataSourceBpa" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapterBpa"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="showSql" value="false"></property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean id="instrumentationLoadTimeWeaverBpa"
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- ############################################################################## -->
                    <!-- DataSource -->
   <!-- ############################################################################## -->

    <bean id="basicDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/r_ncrmextraction" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="fast" />
    </bean>

        <bean id="basicDataSourceBpa" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="fast" />

    </bean>

    <!-- traduction des exceptions -->
    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
    <!-- annotations de persistance -->
    <bean id="persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />



</beans>
```

---

My DAO Class

```
public class daoImpl implements Idao,Serializable {

String BDD_REF="r_multi_4";

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(daoImpl.class);

 @PersistenceContext(unitName="ncrm_extraction")
    EntityManager em;


 @PersistenceContext(unitName="BpaProduciton")
    EntityManager emBpa;



 @Transactional
    public int UpdateExt(String pk_obj_id_Rem,String Req) {
        logger.debug("@@@ DAO : Modifier le flag EXT table  remise : "+pk_obj_id_Rem );
        Query q = emBpa.createNativeQuery(Req);
//      q.setParameter("Date", dteTr);
//      q.setParameter("pk_obj_id_Rem", pk_obj_id_Rem);

        int flag=q.executeUpdate();


        return flag;
    }
```

My persistence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ncrm_extraction" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- <class>com.ncrm.dao.entities.user</class> -->

    </persistence-unit> 

    <persistence-unit name="BpaProduciton" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- <class>com.ncrm.dao.entities.user</class> -->
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: what is the spring version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

suppose you modify your DaoImpl as below.

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
public int UpdateExt(String pk_obj_id_Rem,String Req) {
        logger.debug("@@@ DAO : Modifier le flag EXT table  remise : "+pk_obj_id_Rem );
        Query q = emBpa.createNativeQuery(Req);
        int flag=q.executeUpdate();
        return flag;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Refer this [post](https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/spring-framework/updating-entities-with-update-query-spring-data-jpa) for more details.

Comment: thank you for All your responses , i resolved the problem by adding the name of transaction because i have more then one JpaTransactionManager in My application Context